# regex match return first match from string _ JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for matching digits from a time format like this:

```
let time  = "12:33".match(/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?/)
```

but my logs is something like this:

```
[ '12', index: 0, input: '12:33', groups: undefined ]
```

the only return is the first match not an array of matches.
I even changed my regex for many times. **/\d+/**

but same result.is it something related with my regex pattern?

Comment: `.match(/\d+/g)` will fetch all of them.

Comment: You can just use `/(\d{2}):(\d{2})/.exec("12:33")`, which will return `["12:33", "12", "33", index: 0, input: "12:33", groups: undefined]`

Comment: wow I just thought before of this, this tags like (g, i ) and etc are just global convention for other languages